# Starting Jmeter server with python script, base directory

Tags: python, jmeter

I need to start JMeter-server on target host with some python script. Jmeter has temporary directory like ***/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/***. Inside the script, I have some BeanShell which is creating a file and it`s needed to have appeared in his own base directory in ***bin/*** directory:

```
File file = new File('errors' + File.separator + fileName);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

But finally, it`s appearing (as well as JMeter-server.log file in ***/root/***)
My python script is (simplified):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd /tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/')
run_jmeter_server_cmd = 'nohup java -jar "/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" -Duser.dir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -Dserver_port=11111 -s -j jmeter-server.log > /dev/null 2>&1'
command = 'echo $$; exec ' + run_jmeter_server_cmd 
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
pid = int(stdout.readline())
```

As you see even tried to send user.dir directory explicitly. 
jmeter-server.log is appearing in /root/ but it says that this jmeter process takes all configs from correct directory:

```
2017-12-20 09:26:49,551 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_DK
2017-12-20 09:26:49,566 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/user.properties
2017-12-20 09:26:49,567 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/system.properties
2017-12-20 09:26:49,567 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: java.rmi.server.hostname=loadtest08-qa
2017-12-20 09:26:49,567 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: user.dir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/
2017-12-20 09:26:49,567 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=10001
..............
2017-12-20 09:26:49,580 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5
2017-12-20 09:26:49,580 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/
2017-12-20 09:26:49,580 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin
```

But all files created by script are going to /root/ directory as well as mentioned jmeter-server.log

The only one solution I found is to combine run and cd command to one, but then i cannot get proper PID for java process:

```
run_jmeter_server_cmd = 'cd /tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar && nohup java -jar "/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" -Duser.dir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -Dserver_port=11111 -s -j jmeter-server.log > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there any way to force jmeter to use his own directory without doing cd in there?

Comment: why don't you add property as -JbaseDir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/ and use baseDir property in script?

Comment: yeah, wanted to understand what is going but I think finally will go with this solution

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to send the base directory as property and use it when needed.

You can send in [JMeter command line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) using as

```
-JbaseDir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/
```

In [server mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#server) you may need to use -G option:

> -G
>
> is used to define JMeter properties to be set in the servers

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to pass this `-Duser.dir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin` parameter **before** calling JMeter so amend your command like:

```
run_jmeter_server_cmd = 'nohup java -Duser.dir=/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin -Dserver_port=11111 -jar "/tmp/jmeter-3sc0ppq5/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" -s -j jmeter-server.log > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

And it should start working as expected. In case of any issues check out *jmeter.log* file, especially look for lines related to `o.a.j.s.FileServer:`.

You can also play with `jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix` property value and consider using the aforementioned [FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) class for dynamic detection of current JMeter home directory.

---

Also be aware start staring from [JMeter version 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) [it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) on next available opportunity.

Comment: Looks like the place of these -D variables is not important